# Javascript Date Object giving out some unusual results

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to fetch all the months and year from a specific date to current date last month, for example : fetching all the months from January, 2019 to December 2022 i.e., current year and my function looks something like this :

```js
const getDates = () => {
  let initialDate = new Date("01/01/2019");
  const currentDate = new Date(`12/01/${new Date().getFullYear()}`);
  let i = 0;
  let dates = [];
  while (initialDate <= currentDate) {
    initialDate.setMonth(i++);
    dates.push(initialDate.toDateString());
  }
  return dates;
};

console.log(getDates());
```

Output :

```
Array [
  "Tue Jan 01 2019",
  "Fri Feb 01 2019",
  "Fri Mar 01 2019",
  "Mon Apr 01 2019",
  "Wed May 01 2019",
  "Sat Jun 01 2019",
  "Mon Jul 01 2019",
  "Thu Aug 01 2019",
  "Sun Sep 01 2019",
  "Tue Oct 01 2019",
  "Fri Nov 01 2019",
  "Sun Dec 01 2019",
  "Wed Jan 01 2020",
  "Mon Feb 01 2021",
  "Tue Mar 01 2022",
  "Sat Apr 01 2023",
]
```

But it gives unusual results after the 15th iteration and I don't know why.

Comment: You set the month to the 11th and get November. You set the month to the 12th and get December. You set the month to the 13th and get January of the following year. You set the month to the 14th and get February of the following year. Note how you get the following year twice.

Comment: `initialDate.setMonth(initialDate.getMonth() + 1)` will work properly

Comment: Note that [`setFullYear`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) accepts up to three arguments.

Comment: @SebastianSimon—re "*You set the month to the 11th and get November…*" Nope, 11 is December. ;-)

Comment: @RobG No, the _11th_ is November. _`11`_ is December, but that’s not _the 11th_. Just like `0` is the 1st, not the 0th (which doesn’t exist).